# Could not update solr-exporter config

Tags: solr, prometheus, solrcloud, solr8.4.1

I am using solr 8.4.1. We have a requirement to include solr metrics in Prometheus and we would like to update the solr exporter config file to match our requirement.But I could not find the Solr-exporter/Prometheus exporter directory structure in my solr instance.
I thought it's bundled by default with solr versions 7.3 +.

Please let me know how to add solr exporter config in my solr instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prometheus exporter is bundled with solr 8.4.1; if it isn't in your installation you might have installed it from somewhere else. However, you [can download the old 8.4.1 binaries](https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/8.4.1/) (as always it's important to note; 8.4.1 is old and vulnerable to the log4j2 exploit, so if you haven't mitigated that, you should upgrade to a more recent version or make sure to upgrade log4j2 at least) and copy the prometheus exporter from that.

I just downloaded the 8.4.1 distribution and it's present:

```
SOLR-8.4.1
├───bin
│   └───init.d
├───contrib
│   ├───analysis-extras
│   │   ├───lib
│   │   └───lucene-libs
│   ├───clustering
│   │   └───lib
│   ├───dataimporthandler
│   ├───dataimporthandler-extras
│   │   └───lib
│   ├───extraction
│   │   └───lib
│   ├───jaegertracer-configurator
│   │   └───lib
│   ├───langid
│   │   └───lib
│   ├───ltr
│   ├───prometheus-exporter    <------
│   │   ├───bin
│   │   ├───conf
│   │   ├───lib
│   │   └───lucene-libs
│   └───velocity
│       └───lib
```

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh. Even in the case of solr cloud, if the contrib directory is absent, can i  copy from the 8.4.1 binary and place it in the solr cloud installation path as shown above?

Comment: You'll need to make sure that it gets loaded: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/solr-plugins.html

Comment: hi @MatsLindh , does solr 8.8 provide any specific improvements in terms of metrics monitoring & visualization? when i checked the release notes, it only states that couple of additional metrics are added and Query performance monitoring panel is also added in grafana. Please let me know if we can continue with 8.4 version itself for visualization requirement or if it would be better to upgrade to 8.8.

Comment: I haven't used either, so I can't say. There's plenty of _other reasons_, including the log4j2 issue where remove code execution is possible, to upgrade to either Solr 8.11.1 or Solr 9. There shouldn't be any reason to use an older version for any new application.